# Validate the list of objects in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to Java. I am trying to validate the list of objects in Array list.

For example,

```
Class Cars()
{
  private String name;
  private int year;
}
Cars car = new Cars();
ArrayList<Cars> al = new ArrayList<Cars>();
car.setName("Hyundai");
car.setYear("2010");
car.setName("Maruti");
car.setYear("2010");
al.add(car)
```

I want to add another car object with "Hyundai" but if my list already contains it, i wanted to change my name to Hyundai1 and then add to the list.

I tried to use,

```
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++)
{
  boolean value = al.get(i).getName().contains("Hyundai");
}

if(value)
{
al.setName("Hyundai1");
}

else
{
al.setName("Hyundai");
}
```

Note : I hardcoded the value "Hyundai" here for making it simpler. Kindly suggest

Comment: You could override `equals` in `Car`, then test the `name` (and only the `name`). Then give it a constructor that takes a `name`. Finally, you can say `if (al.contains(new Car("Hyundai"))`

Comment: What should i compare in the equals method. Is it the OBject Car with the name ?

Comment: BTW  shouldnt it be `car.setName("Hyundai")` not `cars.set....`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you please suggest

Answer (score 1):

As Elliot Suggested:

```
public class Cars {
    private String name;
    private int year;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof Cars)) return false;
        // Check whether they are equivalent Strings or both null
        Cars otherCar = (Cars) other;
        if (this.name == null || otherCar.getName() == null) {
            return this.name == otherCar.getName();
        } else {
            return this.name.equals(otherCar.getName()
        }
    }

    // If two objects are equal, then they must have the same hash code.
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. class has to be written lowercase in java.
2. After a `class` declaration there is no `()`, this is mostly for methods.
3. Your `class` appears to be the abstraction of a car, so I would name it `Car` instead of `Cars`.
4. If you create an object and invoke a setter twice, the first value will be overwritten. You probably wanted to create two objects and set each values accordingly
5. You test the name of the car inside a loop but invoke your actions outside the loop. Your local variable `value` wont be visible there and if it would, it would have the value of the last car in the `list`. So you probably want to act inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you wrote, I believe the following might be what you were trying to do:

```
class Car{

    public Car(){
        this.createdCarNames = new ArrayList();
    }

    private String name;
    private String year;
    private ArrayList<String> createdCarNames;

    /*The following method sets the name of the new Car object.
     *It works by iterating over the list of created car names.
     *If a car name in the list is found to be equal to that which
     *you are attempting to set, concatenate a '1' to its end
     *and set the name of the car object.
     *Else, simply set the name of the Car object.
     *Lastly, the name is added to the list of created car names.
     */

    public void setName(String name){
        for(String carName : createdCarNames){
            if(carName.equals(name))
                this.name = name.concat("1");
            else this.name = name;
        }
        createdCarNames.add(name);
    }
}
```

If you are unsure about any part of the code, feel free to point it out. Hope this helps.